# Why can I only approve or reject this edit?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22388938) suggested edit, I noticed that, for some reason, I could only approve or reject it.

It was not a tag wiki edit. It was just a normal question edit.

[image]]

Why couldn't I Improve or Reject and Edit this edit?

Comment: Maybe because the post was already deleted?

Comment: @rene isn't it possible to edit deleted posts?

Comment: Yes, but not by < 10K users. The real question is: Why wasn't that review task evicted from the queue when the owner deleted their post 2 hours ago. If that was due to a race-condition then I want to be in that race.